# create sr_latch from gates in verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, logic-gates, hardware, hdl

consider this file : tb_sr_latch.v

```
`include "sr_latch.v"

module tb_sr_latch;
    reg [4:0] t_in;
    wire out;

    sr_latch M1(t_in[4], t_in[3], t_in[2], t_in[1], t_in[0], out);

    initial begin
        $dumpfile("tb_sr_latch.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0);
        t_in = 5'b00000;
        repeat(32) begin
            #1 t_in = t_in + 5'b00001;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

and this file : sr_latch.v

```
module sr_latch(input set, reset, enable, preset, clear, output out);
    assign out = ((!clear && (preset || !(reset && enable))) && 
            (!clear && (preset || (out || (enable && set)))));
endmodule
```

I compiled tb_sr_latch.v with the following command:

```
iverilog tb_sr_latch.v -o a.out
```

and when I tried to run a.out with the following command:

```
./a.out
```

it stuck [maybe] in a loop with this message:

```
VCD info: dumpfile tb_sr_latch.vcd opened for output.
```

Can anyone help me to solve my problem ? please tell me where Im wrong and why it happends, because I know it is possible to implement it with always block instead of using gates.

Comment: The issue is called an update (or delta) loop.

Answer (score 0):

A signal should not exists on the left and right side of an `assign` statement. A latch should be assigned in it own `always @*` block (with SystemVerilog use `always_latch`) and use non-blocking assignments (`<=`).

When all possible inputs combinations are described in an `always @*` then the block describes combinational logic. If it is not fully described then a latch is inferred. Unintentionally latches are troublesome for all RTL designers.

Non-blocking assignments (`<=`) should be used for the same reason it should be used for edge-sensitive flip-flops (hint simulation race conditions). In addition it helps identify intentional latches; but most synthesizers don’t care.

Note most FPGAs do not support level-sensitive latches or have limited support.

Your sr_latch should look something like this (not tested or syntax checked).

```
module sr_latch(input set, reset, enable, preset, clear, output reg out);
  always @* begin
    if (clear) out <= 1'b0;
    else if (preset) out <= 1'b1;
    else if (enable && reset) out <= 1'b0;
    else if (enable && set) out <= 1'b1;
    // inferred latch since not all possible conditions are defined
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: so you mean it is not possible to create a latch with gates in verilog and not with if else ... ? because I did that in this way and it is still not working:

Comment: module sr_latch(input set, reset, enable, preset, clear, output reg out);

        reg B, D, F, C , E, G, H;
        always @* begin
                out <= B & C;
                B <= D & !clear;
                D <= preset | !F;
                F <= reset & enable;
                C <= !clear & E;
                E <= G | preset;
                G <= out | H;
                H <= enable & set;
        end
endmodule

Comment: A simple sr latch can be written in gate level with two nor gates (or two nand with active low inputs). A typical sr latched with enable pin is often down with four nand gates. Your design has set/reset with and without an enable pin. It is not clear which conditions has priority then there is a conflict.